# How to read a single .txt file as input in C++ without specifying argc

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a program that reads in a single .txt file. The problem is that the only way I am familiar with doing this by using

```
int main ( int argc, char *argv[] ).
```

However, all of my inputs will accept only one file all of the time so I feel like making the user specify that argc=2 every time that they run the program is redundant. Is there a way to make C++ know implicitly that there will only be one command line argument?

Comment: No. But the user doesn't specify `argc` manually, the OS deducts this from the actual number of arguments passed to your program. All you have to do is add a simple `if` for validation.

Comment: That's awesome! I had no clue. The way that it was explained to me it sounded like the user specified it. Thanks!

Comment: Oh! I see. Well in that case, here's an example: On the command line (`cmd.exe` if you're on Windows), type the name of your program followed by all the arguments separated by spaces (quoted, if they contain spaces). For example `report_mouse_count "mice.txt"` Your program will be invoked with `argc` set to 2, and `argv` containing two items, the first being the program name itself (something like `report_mouse_count`) and the second being `mice.txt`. Of course, the user can specify any number of parameters, which is why you still have the validate `argc` to make sure they called it OK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `argc` variable contains the actual number of arguments with which was the program called. It is set automatically when your `main` function is entered. You can't say what this number will be, neither can it be set manually by the user running the program.

If you want to allow your program to be run only with specific number of arguments (in your case one argument), you have to perform check in you `main` function:

```
if (argc != 2)
{
    std::cerr << "Invalid number of arguments" << std::endl;
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition of the [other answer by ips](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26895406/841108), you should remember than any hosted environment of the [C99](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99) (or C11) standard language gives your the arguments `int argc` and `char**argv` for `main` in an implementation specific way.

On DOS and Windows, it is rumored that the command line interface of the operating system is parsing the command line into arguments for `main`.

On POSIX systems and Linux, it is specified that each program starts thru the [POSIX exec functions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/exec.html) which for Linux translates to the [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) syscall. On such systems, the [shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell) is expanding the command into an array of arguments -for `execve`- so may do some [globbing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29): see [glob(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html). But the program is starting with an initial stack containing (notably) the arguments to `main`. The details are [ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) specific, for Linux on x86-64, read the [x86-64 ABI spec](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation_folder/abi.pdf).

You are guaranteed that `argc` is >0, that all the first `argc` elements of `argv` are null terminated strings and are not pointer aliases, and that `argv[argc]` is the `NULL` pointer. So if you want exactly one program argument you should test that `argc==2` and you should use `argv[argc]` as your program argument.

In practice you should always test `argc` and `argv`. [GNU glibc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) offers two way to parse [program arguments](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Program-Arguments.html#Program-Arguments): the usual [getopt](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html) and also [argp](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Argp.html).

The [GNU coding standard](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/standards.html) specify that every program should accept at least `--help` and `--version` program arguments. I hate programs which don't follow that rule, so please follow it...

BTW, for programs processing text files (e.g. [cat(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cat.1.html) ...), it is customary to process every program argument (which is not some option starting with `-`) as a file path, so your program should probably loop on the components (after the first of rank 0, which is conventionally the program name) of `argv` array.